# Mimes Validation not working correctly in Laravel 9

Tags: laravel

My webpage contains a file for upload, and I want the file uploaded only to be either jpg, jpeg or png.

My HTML looks like this:

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="autoSizingInput">Brand Image</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="autoSizingInput" name="brand_image"
        aria-describedby="emailHelp">
    @error('brand_image')
    <span class="text-danger"> {{ $message }}</span>
    @enderror
</div>
```

for checking files I used:

```php
$request->validate(
[
    'brand_image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png'
]);
```

when I upload pdf files it shows an error but when I upload any gif file it doesn't show any error.

Comment: i am getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $rules = [          
            'brand_image' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        $validator->validate();
```

Try something like this

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it should work**

```
     $Rules = [   'brand_image' => 'required|mimes:jpg,jpeg,png',
    ];
    $Validator = Validator::make($r->all(), $Rules);
    if ($Validator->fails()) {
        return back()->withErrors($Validator->errors()->all());
    } else {
  Code....
}
```